# export to iCloud drive via UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, icloud, icloud-drive

In iMovie for iOS, I can export a movie via `UIActivityViewController` to the iCloud drive (shown below). How can I implement this in my own app? Do I need to create a custom `UIActivity`? Currently "iCloud Drive" doesn't show up as one of the action categories.

[image: iMovie share dialog]

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing. My hunch is that it's a custom activity, since it takes you straight to a custom export dialog.

Comment: What did you find out about this?